# flutter GetX: migrating statefulwidget's setState()

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to migrate my map here over to using getx state management. How do I convert the setstate() portion? I want to use a stateless widget. I have a separate view and controller.

This my MapPage code here. It is still a stateful widget as I could not figure out how to address the setstate portion in my getx LocationController. Basically I need to show the LoadScreen while the GoogleMap loads.

```
class MapsPage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final GoogleMapController _googleMapController =
      Get.put(GoogleMapController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Obx(
      () => locationController.currentLatLng == null
          ? LoadScreen()
          : Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        //get user location
                        target: locationController.currentLatLng!,
                        zoom: 16),
                    minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(15.5, 19),
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(
                      LatLngBounds(
                        northeast: LatLng(43.7970928, -79.3067414),
                        southwest: LatLng(43.592580, -79.483674),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    ));
  }
}
```

How will I need to edit my location controller?

```
class LocationController extends GetxController {
  static LocationController instance = Get.find();
  Position? myLocation;
  Rx<Geolocator>? geolocator = Geolocator().obs;
  LatLng? currentLatLng;
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    getpermission();
  }

  getpermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
      return Future.error("location service is not enabled");
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      //do stuff here
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        //stuff
        return Future.error("location permissions denied");
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error("location permissions permanently denied");
    }

    myLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  //next func here
}
```

And this is the error I am currently getting in terminal:

```
The following message was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state:
_ObxState#66e23):
      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables
      into
GetX/Obx
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an
      Obx/GetX.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Obx
  Obx:file:///Users/juliapak/Documents/my%20programs/coffeesoc/lib/pages/mapview_page.da
  rt:16:15
```

Comment: I believe you have already converted your code to stateless using obx. Are you getting any issue here?

Comment: My mappage is a stateful widget, I will edit my question to include the mappage code fully

Comment: SUGGESTION: If you haven't resolved the problem/answered your question, you might want to consider contacting the GetX author, Jonny  Borges, directly.

Answer (score 2):

When using GetX package, you will not be in need to use `setState` any more..

In the Controller class where you put the functions and logic, in the end of each function you have to use `update();` function to update the UI instead of the `setState`.

Also there are 3 ways to use GetX to manage the state in your project..

- GetXBuilder
- GetX
- Obx

GetXBuilder doesn't work in stream but it's so comfortable for the Ram of the device, so that when you will use it you have to put `update();` in the end of the function to update UI.

GetX & Obx are working in stream, so that they don't require to use `update();` but you have to use `.obs` with variables.

For the error that happened with you, You are using Obx but there some variables are not suitable to it, so take a look on them you may have to add `.obs` for someone.

And by the way, in the UI class It's prefer to put the whole scafold widget inside the Obx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. Please change based on the variables you have defined in the controller.

```
class MapsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GoogleMapController _googleMapController =
      Get.put(GoogleMapController());
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(() => _googleMapController.currentLatLng.value == null
          ? LoadScreen()
          : Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        //get user location
                        target: currentLatLng!,
                        zoom: 16),
                    minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(15.5, 19),
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds(
                      LatLngBounds(
                        northeast: LatLng(43.7970928, -79.3067414),
                        southwest: LatLng(43.592580, -79.483674),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It did not work. I am getting an error about improper use of getx. I just editted my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please try now?